# Codeigniter 4 Email sending with HTML as message

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

can you help me figure out a way to use the email class of CI4 to send an email with an HTML as the message?

in Codeigniter 3 it is simple and goes like this:

```
$email->message($this->load->view('html_page_to_send_from_view_folder',$data,true));
```

but in Codeigniter 4 I tried doing this:

```
$email->setMessage(echo view('html_page_to_send_from_view_folder',$data,true));
```

It gives out an error:

```
syntax error, unexpected echo(T_ECHO), expecting ')'
```

I also tried putting the view in a variable like so:

```
$echo_page = echo view('html_page_to_send_from_view_folder',$data,true);
$email->setMessage($echo_page);
```

but it just throws the same error, I was searching all over the internet and the documentation but couldn't find a way to do this. Help please.

I tried this but got no error, and also got no email :'(

```
$echo_page = view('html_page_to_send_from_view_folder',$data,true);
$email->setMessage($echo_page);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got it now I made it work by adding this code $email->setNewLine("\r\n"); at the end just after the setMessage:

```
$email->setMessage($my_message);    
$email->setNewLine("\r\n");
```

and also I set the SMTP port 587 instead of 465:

```
$config['SMTPPort']= 587;
```

ALSO, for the setMessage, I did it like this:

```
$my_message = view('html_page_to_send_from_view_folder',["id" => $data['id']]);
$email->setMessage($my_message);
```

really weird man....

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://onlinewebtutorblog.com/codeigniter-4-send-email-using-custom-template/), if you want to use some template as your message body, you should do something like this:

```
// Using a custom template
$template = view("email-template", []);
    
$email->setMessage($template);
```

CodeIgniter 4 documentation [states](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html):

```
setMessage($body)
Parameters:  $body (string) – E-mail message body
Returns:     CodeIgniter\Email\Email instance (method chaining)
Return type: CodeIgniter\Email\Email

Sets the e-mail message body:
$email->setMessage('This is my message');
```

Comment: tried it, but still no email sending and no errors on my side

Comment: @SeighthHellsing does e-mail body being set correctly? could you debug your sending process?

Answer (score 0):

**A.** Firstly,

Instead of:❌

`$echo_page = echo view('html_page_to_send_from_view_folder',$data,true);`

Use this:✅

`$echo_page = view('html_page_to_send_from_view_folder',$data);`

*Notice the luck of an `echo` statement and **not** passing `true` as the third argument of the [`view(...)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/6b215f99897533f9bd4b54b73b53e994111bf744/system/Common.php#L1121) hepler function.*

**B.** Secondly, to submit HTML-based emails, ensure that you've set the [`mailType`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/6b215f99897533f9bd4b54b73b53e994111bf744/system/Email/Email.php#L140) property to `html`. This can be achieved by using the [`setMailType()`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/6b215f99897533f9bd4b54b73b53e994111bf744/system/Email/Email.php#L751) method on the Email instance. I.e:

`$email->setMailType('html');`

Alternatively, you could set the *"mail type"* by passing an array of preference values to the email [`initialize()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#setting-email-preferences) method. I.e:

```php
public function sendMail(): bool
{
    $email = \Config\Services::email();

    $email->initialize([
        'SMTPHost' => 'smtp.mailtrap.io',
        'SMTPPort' => 2525,
        'SMTPUser' => '479d7c109ae335',
        'SMTPPass' => '0u6f9d18ef3256',
        'SMTPCrypto' => 'tls',
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'mailType' => 'html',
        'mailPath' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail',
        'SMTPAuth' => true,
        'fromEmail' => 'from@example.com',
        'fromName' => 'DEMO Company Name',
        'subject' => 'First Email Test',
    ]);

    $email->setTo('to@example.com');
    $email->setMessage(view('blog_view'));

    $response = $email->send();

    $response ? log_message("error", "Email has been sent") : log_message("error", $email->printDebugger());

    return $response;

}
```

Comment: I already solved the problem I just can't accept my own answer within two days, but thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet from the CodeIgniter 4 docs that I have modified to send HTML Emails.

You can refer to it from the CI4 documentation in this link -https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

```
<?php

$email = \Config\Services::email();

$email->setFrom('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$email->setTo('someone@example.com');
$email->setCC('another@another-example.com');
$email->setBCC('them@their-example.com');

$email->setSubject('Email Test');

// Note: Do not use echo as we need the rendered page as plain text/html
$message = View('path_to_your_email_template_file', ['data' => 'to_your_file']); 

$email->setMessage($message);

// If you forget the line below, it may render the email as plain text(the raw code)

$this->email->setMailType('html');  

$email->send();
```

You will also need to make changes to you `app/config/Email.php` file to allow CI4 to send emails from your server.