# Sending Email By Loading View File in CI4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm facing an issue with my code. I'm actually loading view using `View()`, but instead of sending email it rendering the view. I'm way much confused why its happening? Here is my code.

```
namespace App\Libraries;

use App\Libraries\Options; // Loading Options Library

class CustomEmail
{
    private $email;
    private $option;


    public function setProtcols()
    {
        $this->option = new Options(); // Loading Options Library
        $this->option->load(); // Loading Options


        $this->email = \Config\Services::email();

        $config['charset']  = 'utf-8';
        $config['wordWrap'] = true;
        $config['mailType'] = 'html';

        if ($this->option->key->smtp_active == 1) {
            $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
            $config['SMTPHost'] = $this->option->key->smtp_host;
            $config['SMTPUser'] = $this->option->key->smtp_username;
            $config['SMTPPass'] = $this->option->key->smtp_password;
            $config['SMTPPort'] = $this->option->key->smtp_port;
            $config['SMTPCrypto'] = $this->option->key->smtp_encryption;
        }

        $this->email->initialize($config);
    }

    public function sendMail($to, $subject, $data, $view = 'emails/default')
    {
        $this->setProtcols();
        $this->email->clear();

        $data = array_merge($data, [
            'base_url'                      => base_url(),
            'web_name'                      => $this->option->key->web_name,
            'address'                       => $this->option->key->address,
            'company_registration_number'   => $this->option->key->company_registration_number,
            'whatsapp_number'               => $this->option->key->whatsapp_number,
            'phone_number'                  => $this->option->key->phone,
        ]);


        $body = view($view, $data);
        
        $this->email->setFrom($this->option->key->email, $this->option->key->web_name);
        $this->email->setTo($to);
        $this->email->setSubject($subject);
        $this->email->setMessage($body);

        if ($this->email->send()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The expected output is to send email with the HTML in the view by not rendering/displaying the view.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Codeigniter 4 Email sending with HTML as message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72472989/codeigniter-4-email-sending-with-html-as-message)

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa Well my code written the same way answered in your mentioned question. I'm still facing issue, instead of setting up email to `setMessage` it it actually printing the view. Which is not OK. I want the view to send via email without printing it.

Comment: If you found an answer to your problem, you may [answer your own question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250204/can-you-answer-your-own-questions-on-stack-overflow) instead of submitting an answer in the question description. Check [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an `undefined` variable inside my view, I just defined it and its start working.

It was something which wasn't leaving any error log, even in debug mode I wasn't leaving any traces.

I tried to see the last of the response, the HTML code I was getting! and were ending some where in the middle of view, I just go to that view file saw a variable was there, I further checked my library and I came to know that I was passing `$phone` while in view I wrote `$number` in my view.

I hope this will help others.